# Тире или двоеточие с прямой речью

Tags: тире-или-двоеточие

Зададимся вопросом – что это – случайность или целенаправленные действия тех, кто хочет все испортить?
Правильно ли стоят тире, или где-то должно быть двоеточие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два тире тут явный перебор; в остальном  - возможны варианты:

1. *Зададимся вопросом: что это – случайность или целенаправленные действия тех, кто хочет все испортить?*
2. *Зададимся вопросом, что это – случайность или целенаправленные действия тех, кто хочет все испортить?*
3. *Зададимся вопросом, что это: случайность или целенаправленные действия тех, кто хочет все испортить?*

---

Попутно:

[если косвенный вопрос содержит сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию, в конце сложноподчиненного предложения ставится вопросительный знак.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88,6)

Comment: Мне больше нравится 2-й вариант.